# handle ruby process termination after clicking "X"

Tags: ruby, exception, signals

I know that we can handle Ctrl-C using

```
rescue Exception, or 

rescue SystemExit, or 

trap(0) or 

trap("SIGTERM") or 

trap("INT"),
```

but I want to handle the break from clicking "X" button to close the command prompt, the requirement is to record some progress when the program is terminated abnormal, e.g. system reboot or clicking "X" button, then I can continue to work from the breaking point the next time,

I tried all of them, none worked.

did you have any suggestions? is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
begin
  10.times do |second|
    @second = second
    sleep 1
  end
ensure
  File.open("/tmp/terminated.txt", 'w') do |f| 
    f.write("Process terminated after #{@second} second(s)")
  end
end
```

The code in the `ensure` block will always run, even if process terminates by Ctrl-C or closing the terminal window.

It will also run if the process is not terminated. This could be prevented by checking if the loop has finished. `File.open(...) unless @second == 10`

Comment: It might be windows doesn't has a /tmp directory. You could try changing the file path or replacing the File block with a different action like `puts "... #{@seconds}"`.

Comment: yes, i saw that problem and did the file path change, but result is the same: Ctrl-C worked, Clicking "X" failed.

Comment: Just FYI: an ensure block is not triggered on a SIGKILL.

Comment: Closing a terminal on a Mac, or even force quitting a terminal, triggers the ensure block. But it looks like Windows will send a SIGKILL or similar. From the article linked below, "SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored by your programs". http://www.thattommyhall.com/2011/02/24/rescue-exception-harmful-signals-in-ruby/

Comment: thanks very much, then I think it can't be achieved in windows